# error when reading file gcc version 4.4.7 but not gcc 6.1

Tags: c, gcc

I am simply trying to read a file using fscanf, but I get Segmentation fault when I try to fclose() or free the char* I am writing the contents of the file to. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if(fp == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: File not found.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char* directive = malloc(9);
    while(fscanf(fp,"%s",directive) != EOF){
        printf("%s\n",directive);
    }
    //fclose(fp); Seg fault
    //free(directive); free(): invalid next size (fast)
    return 0;
}
```

What is even more unusual is that when I run this code my own computer with gcc version 6.1 it works fine, but running it on a server with gcc 4.4.7 doesn't work.

Edit: This is the file I am trying to read

```
.byte   0000045d    00
.byte   00000457    09
.byte   00000458    09
.byte   00000141    0a
.byte   00000183    0a
.byte   000001ca    0a
.byte   0000020d    0a
.size   0800
.string "Enter new char"
.byte   00000251    0a
.byte   00000262    0a
.byte   00000263    0a
.byte   0000029d    0a
.byte   000002d3    0a
.byte   0000030c    0a
.byte   00000345    0a
.byte   00000346    0a
.byte   0000036d    0a
.byte   000003b0    0a
.byte   000003e9    0a
.byte   00000409    0a
.byte   00000442    0a
```

Comment: I presume you mean "when I compile with gcc x.y and run" rather than "when I run with gcc x.y".

Comment: try `"%s"` --> `"%8s"` to `fscanf`

Comment: We'll assume that by "run this code" you actually provided a file that opened, and the data within (which was oddly not presented with your question) was provided to the `fscanf` call for processing. If you think that mysterious data and the size of that `char` array you allocated are related, you're right.

Comment: `while(fscanf(fp,"%8s",directive) == 1)` because testing `EOF` won't trap when 0 items are read.

Comment: @Weather Vane  Agree testing `== 1` better, yet I see no case where  `fscanf(fp,"%s",directive)` returns 0.

Comment: How do I account for the fact that the first string I want to read in might not always have a length of 8 but the max length it can have is 7

Comment: @chux yes I spotted that for `%s` but left it as good practice.

Comment: @TomCoda you would do better to read each whole line with `fgets` and then examine it.

Comment: Candidate corner issues: Insure `argc > 1` before attempting `argv[1]`.  Insure `directive != NULL`

Comment: Provide exact error/fault message.

Comment: Well, with given input I see no reason `"%8s"` solves the problem, even tough using `"%s"` is definitely bad practice.

Comment: As @chux, you didn't test `argc`, and when I forget to supply a filename it crashes. Otherwise, code posted works perfectly with example data.

Comment: Given that input, I see no problem, even with the `fclose` and `free` calls uncommented. The code is error-prone given bad input, and that should be fixed, but I don't see why it should die with a seg fault given the input in the question.

Comment: Are you sure they are no fake spaces in you input file? You should try to replace `printf("%s\n",directive);` with something such as `printf("directive=<%s>\n",directive);`

Comment: @jdarthenay printing as suggested is good, but may be too late given your good idea/concern about `fscanf(fp,"%s",directive)` lacking a width limit.

Comment: I think I have resolved it, I realized the directive was being filled with values larger than 8 characters so I simply changed the fcanf line to:
`fscanf(fp,"%s\t%x\t%x",directive,&mem_location,&value)`

Comment: `fscanf(fp,"%s\t%x\t%x"` will choke on `.byte   0000020d    0a .size   0800 .string "Enter new char" .byte   00000251    0a`  The `'\t'` in `"%s\t%x\t%x"` serves little functional purpose.  And with this code change it is even _more_ important to to test against `== 3` rather than `!= EOF`.  Why haven't you coded an `8` in `"%8s"`?

Comment: 1) Drop the `fscanf()`, 2) Use 100 byte line buffer 3) Use `fgets()` 4) use `sscanf()/strtol()` 5) Check for error returns.

Comment: Two points: (1) `fscanf %s` is an accident waiting to happen, but *especially* with a tiny array of just 9 bytes.  (2) the scanf family is a toy, anyway; nobody uses those functions for serious programming, because they're far too inflexible and have far too many foibles.  You *might* be able to get `fscanf` to work for your problem, but (a) you're going to have to coddle it with generously big buffers (`directive = malloc(100)`) and/or restrictive format specifiers (`%8s`), and (b) you're not going to be able to effectively deal with free-form strings like `.string "Enter new char"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have resolved it, I realized the directive was being filled with values larger than 8 characters so I simply changed the fcanf line to: `fscanf(fp,"%s\t%x\t%x",directive,&mem_location,&value)` – Tom Coda